# Javascript opacity hover and infinite scrolling

Tags: javascript, scroll, hover, opacity

I have this piece of code for my images, so the opacity can lower when not hovering over them.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("img").css("opacity", 0.8);
    $("img").hover(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 1.0
        }, 500);
    }, function () {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 0.8
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Except, I'm also using this infinite scrolling code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://codysherman.com/tools/infinite-scrolling/code"></script>
```

And together I only get the first photos to become opaque as defined when the page initially loads. Once I scroll down and new images are loaded with the infinite-scrolling script, the opacity has no effect on them.

How can I get this to work in conjunction with the infinite scrolling script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery event delegation instead of `hover`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on('mouseenter', 'img', function () {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 1.0
        }, 500);
    }).on('mouseleave', 'img', function () {
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 0.8
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

The image opacity should not be set via JavaScript, but as a true CSS rule instead.

Comment: So how should the animations work on IE8 and below if they are done with pure CSS?

Comment: All jQuery does is modify a number of CSS values to cover all the bases for browser support. If you set the CSS following this guide, jQuery should deal with the rest: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/

Comment: The opacity should effect photos on page load rather than mousing over them individually.

Comment: @MurQuirk I'm not sure I understand what you're saying -- if you set the original CSS for images to be at a lowered opacity they will stay at that unless you mouse over, in which case they will animate to 100% opacity. In fact, this entire effect can be achieved with CSS transitions if legacy browser support isn't vital.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the events to the dynamically generated elements:

```
$("body").on('hover', 'img', function () {
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: 1.0
    }, 500);
}, function () {
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: 0.8
    }, 500);
});
```

Replace `body` with the element that contains all of the `<img />` tags.